# Call function from Directive to Controller [AngularJs]

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have an app that can will send a message with attachment.
I am using this kind of module called **angular-media-preview** 
[here is the link](http://www.codekraft.it/demos/angular-media-preview/)

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxsOs.png)

I have a reset button in my app. Now, I cant reset the fields of my input file type. is there any possible way to call onchange event for my input file will be reset or any work arounds?

**UPDATE**

https:REMOVEME//jsfiddle.net/cbh46wb8/

dont mind the preview thing, I dont know why image preview is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<input type="file" ng-click="clear()">
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.clear = function () {
    angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
};
```

Comment: but the preview of the image file is still there